# Update jboss/base-jdk 8 to 11 in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak 7.0 with Docker ([jboss/keycloak:7.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jboss/keycloak/7.0.0/images/sha256-6e6b94949242c9f36bb52be680af3d7bc7903b42813103fc33ad0a811448bf96)), and I've some features developed using Java 11 but the java version available in this image is the Java 8.

I tested the jboss/base-jdk:11 in Dockerfile and the build was successful.

```
FROM jboss/base-jdk:8
```

Are there any planning to update jboss/base-jdk:8 to jboss/base-jdk:11 or greater in Dockerfile?

Comment: It would be better to create issue at keycloak Jira https://www.keycloak.org/community.html